# How can I create a Continued Figure Caption?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I have two figures with somehow the same caption, see the code:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]\centering
\includegraphics[height=18cm]{pic1}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\begin{figure}[!ht]\centering
\includegraphics[height=18cm]{pic2}
\caption{(continued)}
\end{figure}
```

Is there a way to have only the first figure referenced in the list of figures?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `caption` package which gives you access to the `\ContinuedFloat` float command (to keep the figure number the same) and an additional field to the `\caption` which when used but left empty prevent the figure to be mentioned in the List of Figures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=18cm]{pic1}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\includegraphics[height=18cm]{pic2}
\caption[]{caption (continued)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you use the `subfig` package as well, you can also include the graphics inside a `subfloat` which would enable you to give each graphic it own caption in addition to the main figure one:

```
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=18cm]{pic2}}
```

this would then use an `alpha` counter within the figure to differentiate between the parts. The second `[]` can contain the `subfloat` caption.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to type the `[]` to the second caption.

Comment: I'll just delete my answer then, as yours has the same info, and the added suggestion about subfloats (and you posted first).  I'll also delete my comment above.

Comment: Thanks @TorbjørnT. I have fixed the explanation of which package does what.